# Sleep or semaphore for background thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, semaphore, objective-c++, thread-sleep

I have third party code which creates a lot of threads with code like this:

```
while (true) {
    {
        my::Lock lock(&mMutex); // mutex implementation in c++
        if (!reseting) {
            // some code
            break;
        }
    }
    usleep(1000 / 20); // 20 time per second
}
```

I can rewrite this code with `semaphore`. What to use, `semaphore` or `sleep`? As I understood they work same. `Semaphore` will work little bit faster because we can immediately continue this `thread` when `reset` is changed.

Or maybe you have another idea how to do this better?

---

Implementation of `my::Lock`:

```
Lock::Lock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex) {
    _mutex = mutex;
    pthread_mutex_lock(_mutex);
}

Lock::~Lock() {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(_mutex);
}
```

Comment: `my::Lock` unlocks mutex when release. This object release before `usleep`. This process in background do a lot of calculation with sometimes sleep code, so I believe when sleep is calls processor still work but on another thread.

Comment: Ah, re unlocking when released, that makes sense. That explains the cryptic `{` scoping. I'm not sure how the other thread uses the same lock, though (as I assume the purpose of that lock is to synchronize `reseting`). Even if that wasn't a problem, I'm not a fan of this implicit unlocking pattern. But all of that is moot, as the broader issue is that polling, in general, (ignoring the fact that using mutex lock!) 20 times per second, is inefficient. Using delegate or completion block or notifications or some other proactive process would be better. Avoid spinning/waiting if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that polling is an inefficient approach. This mutex lock implementation only makes it worse.

You ask if a semaphore might be better pattern: It probably is, but I suspect you can do even better. Specifically, three asynchronous patterns come to mind:

- The "completion handler" pattern, where the API call takes a block parameter which is a block of code that will be called when the asynchronous task is complete. This is ideal when you need a simple interface for informing the caller of the completion of the asynchronous task.
- The "[delegate-protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11)" pattern, where the API would have a `delegate` property to specify who to inform and a protocol that defines what methods the `delegate` may or must implement. This is useful pattern where the interface for communicating updates is more complicated (e.g. not simply when the task is complete, but perhaps various progress updates, too).
- The "notification" pattern (using `NSNotificationCenter` to inform other object(s) of status changes). This is useful if it's possible that more than one object may want to be informed of the completion of the task.

Frankly, the choice may be dictated by the details of this third-party library. It's hard to assess on the basis of the information provided.

Comment: This code has wrote for different architecture. How I know it's bad practise to use sleep. Will I get more app performance if I rewrite all this code with "completion handler" pattern for example. Right now there create 4-5 threads where going a lot of calculation. When one thread are sleeping, processor calculate in another thread. Also if I rewrite to some pattern, code will be less readable.

Comment: Yep, polling and `usleep` isn't great, but using semaphores often isn't much better, IMHO. It depends. But, from a practical perspective, it's quite possible that a more significant refactoring this code isn't worth the effort, as the gains may be modest. This all smells of premature optimization, as it is.